# Force JMenuItem size

Tags: java, swing, imageicon, jmenuitem

When I add an icon to a `JMenuItem`, it's scaled up to the size of the icon. See the difference here:

[image: The problem]

Can I somehow force  it to scale back down to original? If not, is there default icon size for `JMenuItem` (meaning, what would be the size of the icon when it would perfectly fit in Test1,2,3's icon slot)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to solve this, is to rescale the icon itself :

```
 ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon((getClass().getResource("new.png")));
 Image image = i.getImage(); // transform it
 Image newimg = image.getScaledInstance(20, 20, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH); // scale it the smooth way 
 i = new ImageIcon(newimg);  // transform it back
```

Then you set this new resized-icon to your `JMenuItem` :

*In fact you can just force the size of `JMenuItem`  by declaring :

```
.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(..,..));
```

but the problem is that the icon won't be scaled, it will look like the following :

[image]

Here is the simple demo I wrote :

```
public class SwingMenuDemo {

private JFrame mainFrame;

public SwingMenuDemo() { prepareGUI(); }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingMenuDemo swingMenuDemo = new SwingMenuDemo();
    swingMenuDemo.showMenuDemo();
}

private void prepareGUI() {
    mainFrame = new JFrame("Java SWING Examples");
    mainFrame.setSize(400, 400);
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
}

private void showMenuDemo() {
    //create a menu bar
    final JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

    //create menus
    JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");

    //create menu items
    JMenuItem test1 = new JMenuItem("test1");
    JMenuItem test2 = new JMenuItem("test2");
    JMenuItem test3 = new JMenuItem("test3");
    JMenuItem test4 = new JMenuItem("test4");

    ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon((getClass().getResource("new.png")));
    Image image = i.getImage(); // transform it
    Image newimg = image.getScaledInstance(20, 20, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH); // scale it the smooth way 
    i = new ImageIcon(newimg);  // transform it back

    test4.setIcon(i);

    fileMenu.add(test1);
    fileMenu.add(test2);
    fileMenu.add(test3);
    fileMenu.add(test4);

    menuBar.add(fileMenu);

    //add menubar to the frame
    mainFrame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

The size of original icon :

[image]

The scaled icon on `JMenuItem` :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> is there default icon size for JMenuItem

I guess you could take a look at the size of the icons used for `JCheckBoxMenuItem` and `JRadioButtonMenuItem` to see what size those icons are.

You can use the UIManager for this:

```
Icon icon = UIManager.getIcon("RadioButtonMenuItem.checkIcon");
Icon icon = UIManager.getIcon("CheckBoxMenuItem.checkIcon");
```

Comment: Gives me 12x12 pixels.